How does one get the paths to affected projects in an NX monorepo?
Context
Currently I am in the process of setting up a polyglot NX monorepo as part of a POC.
Problem overview
I want to re-use existing GitHub actions and workflows, but these act on a sourcecode directory.
In our case this is mostly Node (js/ts) and Go apps.
However using nx affected will only give me the name of the affected project, not the path to the project (which the workflows could be run on).
Problem details
If we were to have a directory structure like this:
apps/
  - foo    # node
  - bar    # go
libs/
  - spam   # ts
  - eggs   # go

then we could solve this by using tags in each respective project.json for the different apps and libs, and filter on that when running nx affected ....
However if you have a more nested folder structure, such as
apps/
  go/
    - bar
  node/
    - foo
libs/
  go/
    - eggs
  ts/
    - spam

Now with this structure, we cannot assume that we can prepend any affected app with apps/ etc.
So what does one do in this case? Either we can use tags that have to be in sync with all of the project.json files in each of the projects. However it's not the most robust solution exactly, since any mistake by moving a directory, changing tags without adjusting the other parts will end up with a mismatch.
Solution wishlist
Preferably I want to be able to use some sort of nx command to get the paths to the affected projects.
Using these I want to set up outputs to be used in a GitHub workflow matrix to to use with other reusable workflows.
Useful links

https://nx.dev/nx-api/nx/documents/affected
https://nx.dev/recipes/enforce-module-boundaries/tag-multiple-dimensions#tag-in-multiple-dimensions
https://nx.dev/features/enforce-module-boundaries#tags
https://blog.nrwl.io/mastering-the-project-boundaries-in-nx-f095852f5bf4


In our case we wanted to also be able to filter based on tags, so I ended up with the following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

# OBS!!! If you make any modifications to this script, please do note that any
# additional echo statements will be printed in the GitHub Actions, and show up as
# an error when trying to use the output as a JSON array.
# This is because the output is expected to be a JSON array, and any additional output
# will break the JSON format. This leads to issues when trying to output the result
# as a GitHub Actions output variable or environment variable.

# Function to get affected projects based on provided tags.
# Usage: get_affected_projects_details [tag1] [tag2] ...
# - If no tags are provided, all affected projects are returned.
# - If tags are provided, only affected projects with the provided tags are returned.
# TODO; Ensure that the multi-tag filtering works as expected
get_affected_projects_details() {
  # Check if the first argument is a help flag
  # If it is, show the help message and return
  if [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo "Usage: get_affected_projects_details [tag1] [tag2] ..."
    echo "Description: Retrieves affected projects. Filters by tags if provided."
    return
  fi

  local rootDirPath=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup) # Path to the root directory
  local graphFile="$rootDirPath.nx/cache/project-graph.json" # Path to the project graph file
  local jqPath='.nodes[$nodeName].data.root' # JQ path to get the root value of a node

  # Check if the graph file exists, if not, run 'nx show projects --json --affected' first
  # ... > /dev/null is used to suppress the output
  # TODO; Investigate if this can instead use the tags, to avoid having to find _all_ affected projects
  # TODO;    If possible, this would allow for a more efficient way to get only the relevant projects
  if [ ! -f "$graphFile" ]; then
    npx nx show projects --json --affected > /dev/null
  fi

  # Initialize excludeString as empty
  excludeString=""

  # Check if there are tags provided
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    # Start with "*", only if there are tags
    excludeString="*"

    # Loop through all provided tags
    for tag in "$@"; do
      # Append each tag prefixed with ",!tag:" to the excludeString
      excludeString+=",!tag:$tag"
    done
  fi

  # Get the affected node names based on the exclude string
  local nodeNames=()
  local readCmd="npx nx show projects --affected"
  [ -n "$excludeString" ] && readCmd+=" --exclude=\"$excludeString\""
  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a nodeNames < <(eval $readCmd && printf '\0')

  local projectDetails=() # Array to hold project details

  # Loop through all node names and get the root value
  for nodeName in "${nodeNames[@]}"; do
    local rootValue=$(jq -r --arg nodeName "$nodeName" "$jqPath" "$graphFile")
    if [ "$rootValue" != "null" ]; then
      # Construct JSON object string for each project
      projectDetails+=("{\"name\":\"$nodeName\",\"root\":\"$rootValue\"}")
    fi
  done

  # Convert array of JSON strings to JSON array string
  projectDetailsString=$(printf "%s\n" "${projectDetails[@]}" | jq -s -c '.')
  # Use GitHub Actions format to set output variable
  echo "$projectDetailsString"
}

# Call the function with all passed arguments
get_affected_projects_details "$@"

